# Python: converting a list of dictionaries to json

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, looking some thing like this:

```
list = [{'id': 123, 'data': 'qwerty', 'indices': [1,10]}, {'id': 345, 'data': 'mnbvc', 'indices': [2,11]}]
```

and so on. There may be more documents in the list. I need to convert these to one JSON document, that can be returned via bottle, and I cannot understand how to do this. Please help. I saw similar questions on this website, but I couldn't understand the solutions there.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

use json library

```
import json
json.dumps(list)
```

by the way, you might consider changing variable list to another name, `list` is the builtin function for a list creation, you may get some unexpected behaviours or some buggy code if you don't change the variable name.

Comment: Okay. This is just a sample, and I am using the name mylist for this. Does dumps() work for lists too? I thought it was only supposed to be used for dicts.

Comment: Is it possible to save the file as  JSON Column Array or JSON row Array?

Comment: NOTE: re-assigning list (list=[1,2,3]) conflicts with the builtin method list(). please keep in mind.

Comment: I want to remove outer arrays, @markcial. Can you please help?

Comment: reply to @Abdul Haseeb take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html and list.pop([i])

Answer (score 64):

```
import json

list = [{'id': 123, 'data': 'qwerty', 'indices': [1,10]}, {'id': 345, 'data': 'mnbvc', 'indices': [2,11]}]
```

**Write to json File:**

```
with open('/home/ubuntu/test.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(list , fout)
```

**Read Json file:**

```
with open(r"/home/ubuntu/test.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
print(data)
#list = [{'id': 123, 'data': 'qwerty', 'indices': [1,10]}, {'id': 345, 'data': 'mnbvc', 'indices': [2,11]}]
```

Comment: NOTE: re-assigning list (list=[1,2,3]) conflicts with the builtin method list(). please keep in mind.

Comment: Wouldn't just data = json.dumps(list, indent=2) be enough? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
response_json = ("{ \"response_json\":" + str(list_of_dict)+ "}").replace("\'","\"")
response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
response_json = json.loads(response_json)
```

Comment: Hi! While this may solve OP's problem, it is generally discouraged to write code only answers on SO. Please provide some explanation as to why this is a solution to the problem as it will help OP better understand and will benefit future visitors of the site. Thanks!