# Merging a list of dictionaries to json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to merge a list of dictionaries into a single json object to be consumed by another json parser.

Here is my list which I fetched from a `requests.get`:

```
list = [{"name":"New York USA"}, {"id":446}]
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "org": {
    "name": "New York USA",
    "id": 446
  }
}
```

Comment: the `json` package has a `dumps` method

Comment: The format of expected json is invalided.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA please use normal quotes, when you edit his post. Original Post has normal Quotes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: converting a list of dictionaries to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525328/python-converting-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-json)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please search Stack Overflow for similar questions.

Comment: The title "Converting a list of dictionaries to json" doesn't currently describe the specifics described in the body, which is more of a problem of building a single object from a list of dictionaries and then converting that to JSON.

Comment: @Paul oh, can you edit / suggest an edit to the title then? And maybe find another dupe...

Comment: @demonking If you see the timeline of the post,you will find he didn't use the normal quote,I just added some backquotes.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be Using  **dictionary comprehension**
(**Note**: This solution will work even if dict has multiple keys and values)

```
list = [{"name":"New York USA"}, {"id":446}]
data = {}
data['org'] = {key:value for item in list for key, value in item.items()}
print(data)
```

`output: {'org': {'name': 'New York USA', 'id': 446}}`

Comment: @user3558255, If this solution really solved your problem, Please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```
import json

list_of_dicts = [{},{}]

json_rep = json.dumps(list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: Does this code producing desired output?
I  tried this code, It is producing output same as input

Answer (score 0):

First merge your all dictionaries in list then, make a new dictionary thn dumps it with json.please try this below

```
import json
list = [{"name":"New York USA"}, {"id":446}]
def Merge(dict1, dict2): 
   res = {**dict1, **dict2} 
   return res 
dic=Merge(list[0],list[1])
print(dic)
new_json={'org':dic}
json_rep = json.dumps(new_json)
print(json_rep)
```

output

```
'{"org": {"name": "New York USA", "id": 446}}'
```