# beginner help wth python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying my first steps with python and json and hope you can halp me with this.
I am getting a json in a variable which looks like this:

```
host10=[{'hostid': '10084', 'proxy_hostid': '0'},
 {'hostid': '10085', 'proxy_hostid': '1'}]
```

when I run

```
hosts = json.loads(host10)
  print(hosts)
```

I am getting the error:

```
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

what do I wrong?

Comment: No, it’s not JSON but a native Python list of dictionaries.

Comment: [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts a string as input - you are providing a list of dicts instead. The error is pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

you can find your answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525328/python-converting-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-json)

```
import json
json.dumps(list_name)
```